# How to make string appear as hyperlink in Html Table using C#

Tags: c#, html, html-table, hyperlink

I am writing a web page in html (with back-end in C#) that displays a list of objects (EventJOINEventDate) that are called from an API in an HtmlTable. Each event has the following attributes: date, name, description, address1, address2, city, state, zip, eventurl, registrationurl, and inviatationurl. The last 3 are links and I want the table to present these as links instead of strings. How can I do that?
BTW I am using Panel1 to present the table.

```
List<EventJOINEventDate> EventList = (List <EventJOINEventDate>)serializer.Deserialize(strresult, typeof(List<EventJOINEventDate>));
    foreach(EventJOINEventDate obj in EventList)
    {
        DateTime StartDateTime = obj.StartDateTime;
        string EventName = obj.EventName;
        string EventDesc = obj.EventDesc;
        string Address1 = obj.Address1;
        string Address2 = obj.Address2;
        string City = obj.City;
        string State = obj.State;
        string Zip = obj.Zip;
        string EventURL = obj.EventURL;
        string RegistrationURL = obj.RegistrationURL;
        string InvitationURL = obj.InvitationURL;
    }
    TestFunc(EventList);
    Panel1.Visible = true;
}
public void TestFunc(List<EventJOINEventDate> events)
{
    HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
    table.Rows.Add(AddFirstRow());
    foreach (EventJOINEventDate item in events)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(AddRow(item));
    }
    Panel1.Controls.Add(table);
}
public HtmlTableRow AddRow(EventJOINEventDate item)
{
    HtmlTableRow result = new HtmlTableRow();
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.StartDateTime.ToString() });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.EventName });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.EventDesc });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.Address1 });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.Address2 });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.City });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.State });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.Zip });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.EventURL });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.RegistrationURL });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.InvitationURL });
    return result;
}
public HtmlTableRow AddFirstRow()
{
    HtmlTableRow result = new HtmlTableRow();
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "Date" });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "Event Name" });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "Event Description" });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "Address1" });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "Address2" });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "City" });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "State" });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "Zip" });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "EventURL" });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "RegistrationURL" });
    result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "InvitationURL" });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.EventURL });
```

create a [`HtmlAnchor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor?view=netframework-4.8) inside the `HtmlTableCell`, something like this

```
var eventLink = new HtmlAnchor() { Href = item.EventURL, InnerHtml = item.EventURL };
var eventCell = new HtmlTableCell();
eventCell.Controls.Add(eventLink);
result.Cells.Add(eventCell);
```

Do this same pattern for each of your links.